# Abort Jasper report generation on NullPointerException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, nullpointerexception

I'm creating reports with Jasper Reports (4.0.0) for our project (JRE 1.6.x).

I'm getting bothered with `NullPointerException`s in my scriptlets, as they do not cause the report to abort, they just make the field be silently evaluated to `null`. As far as I tested, it happens only to NPE's.

The generated reports are quite important and should not have any errors. So, if an exception occurs (like NPE's for some missing data), it should stop the generation, and the database and/or report should be fixed. Such behavior may hide some report coding errors, unless someone spots the missing field.

What is the reason for this behavior with NPE's? Is there any compilation option or execution flag I can switch to make NPE's bubble up as other exceptions do?
I really wish I won't have to wrap every scriptlet method in a `try..catch` block and throw another exception on NPE's.

Thanks!

---

Ok, a sample report. It does not uses scriptlets, but generate the NPE directly on a field evaluation (the result is the same), and can be executed directly on iReport preview without parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="NPE_Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <variable name="NullVariable" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="NotNullVariable" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System">
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[200]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <title>
        <band height="72" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="11" y="10" width="179" height="22"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Successful field evaluation:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="190" y="10" width="296" height="22"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>   
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["0x"+Integer.toHexString($V{NotNullVariable}.intValue()+55)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="11" y="32" width="179" height="22"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NPE on field evaluation:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="190" y="32" width="296" height="22"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["0x"+Integer.toHexString($V{NullVariable}.intValue()+55)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like a null pointer expression problem. It sounds like your data source allows null fields. JasperReports is robust enough to handle a report where some information is missing. There is a property you can set so that when information is missing the field prints "null" or is left blank. If you don't want the report to generate at all if the data field is null, modify your data source so the fields are "not null".

Alternatively, drop on a conditional statement so that your scriptlet only runs if th fields are not null and break if they are. Then when the report hits a null field it will stop.